# Cannot get L1 ratio in LogisticRegressionCV object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit an elastic net model using `LogisticRegressionCV`. I want to see what L1 ratio `LogisticRegressionCV` chooses after cross validation. I read from [its documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) that after fitting we can access it by its attribute `l1_ratio_`. But when I tried this, it failed.

The code is:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=10,cv=3,penalty='elasticnet',refit=True, n_jobs=-1,solver='saga',max_iter=1000).fit(X, y)
clf.l1_ratio_
```

It returns :

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionCV' object has no attribute 'l1_ratio_'

Sklearn version: 0.19.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ElasticNet penalty, and thus `l1_ratios`, `l1_ratios_`, and `l1_ratio_` didn't exist in sklearn v0.19.2.  You can view the [past documentation for v0.20](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html); the parameters appear in [0.21 documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html).